# How to read a file with different extension using php?

Tags: php

I want to read a file with .grf extension. It got folders, files, images etc inside. Its a packed file using GRF Builder. It can also be extracted using the same software but i want to read it using php. Is it possible to do that?

[image: GRF File]

Thanks

Comment: Yes. As for how, though...

Comment: Or look into this class https://github.com/vthibault/ROChargenPHP/blob/master/loaders/class.Grf.php `Load and Parse .grf file (only 0x200 version without DES encryption).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not come with GRF capabilities built-in. You'll need to find 3rd party extensions or classes such as:

https://github.com/vthibault/roBrowser/tree/master/client

https://github.com/vthibault/ROChargenPHP/blob/master/loaders/class.Grf.php

https://github.com/trojal/php-ro